# Laravel Eloquent belongsTo relationship is not working

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a relationship between two tables using Eloquent `belongsTo` but it doesn't seem to work.

the two tables are documents and departments , each document belongs to one department.

documents

```
id INT
department INT
```

departments

```
id INT
name varchar(255)
```

this is the function that defines the relationship

```
public function department(){
    // department: foreign key
    // id : departments table primary key
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Department' , 'department' , 'id');
}
```

and this is the accessor function

```
public function getDepartmentAttribute(){
    return $this->department()->first()->name;
}
```

it returns the following error message: `Undefined property: App\AjaxSearch::$department`

Comment: are you sure $this is a Document model?

Comment: from where are you calling this getDepartmentAttribute()?

Comment: from a model called `AjaxSearch` , it uses documents table.

Comment: Could you remove the slash before `\App\Department` to have `App\Department`? I will rather that you don't use the quote, and simply type `Department::class` so you can be save you are not typing the wrong path to your department model as this will result naturally to the class.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't affect anything , still getting the same error

Comment: do you have this `AjaxSearch` model related to department? Because if you are trying to access the department() from `AjaxSearch` with this `return $this->departments()->first()->name` then the `$this` as `AjaxSearch` model must relate to `department` but at least from your sample code, I couldnt find that.

Comment: Looking at the error message `Undefined property: App\AjaxSearch::$department` there is not `$department` property for ajax search`

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi think It's related with this relation `public function department(){
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Department' , 'department');
    }`

Comment: Didn't you say `Undefined property: App\AjaxSearch::$department` is the error? BTW is the `getDepartmentAttribute()` function inside `Document` or `AjaxSearch` model?

Comment: It's in `AjaxSearch` model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In documents table add

```
department_id INT Foreign
```

In your documents migration

```
$table->integer('department')->unsigned();
```

Also edit the relationship

```
public function department() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'department');
}
```

**Update**

Ok according to your updates, you can get the department name like this

```
$doc = Document::find(1);
$name = $doc->department->name;
```

Comment: I also edited the relationship but it returned `Trying to get property of non-object` error

Comment: Check my updates if they help. Else, I will try agian.

Comment: Still returns the same error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: then try to check if the department exists. `dd($doc->department);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the related record  exists

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Department', 'department');
}
```

$document is your current document record.

```
$name = (empty($document->department->id) === false) ? ($document->department->name) : '';
```